# Custom Collection/List To Store Custom Objects

Tags: c#, list, class

I have a customer object class:

```
  public class customerObject
  {
    private string _address1;
    private string _address2;
    private string _address3;
    private string _category;
    private string _country;
    private string _county;
    private string _custcode;
    private string _fullname;
    private string _int_rep_hou;
    private string _int_rep_key;
    private double _lat;
    private double _lng;
    private string _postcode;
    private string _rep_code;
    private string _telephone;

    public customerObject()
    {
    }

    public string Address1
    {
        get { return _address1; }
        set { _address1 = value; }
    }

    public string Address2
    {
        get
        {
            return _address2;
        }

        set { _address2 = value; }
    }

    public string Address3 { get { return _address3; } set { _address3 = value; } }

    public string Category
    {
        get { return _category; }
        set { _category = value; }
    }

    public string Country { get { return _country; } set { _country = value; } }

    public string County { get { return _county; } set { _county = value; } }

    public string Custcode
    {
        get { return _custcode; }
        set { _custcode = value; }
    }

    public string Fullname
    {
        get { return _fullname; }
        set { _fullname = value; }
    }

    public string Int_rep_hou
    {
        get { return _int_rep_hou; }
        set { _int_rep_hou = value; }
    }

    public string Int_rep_key
    {
        get { return _int_rep_key; }
        set { _int_rep_key = value; }
    }

    public double Lat { get { return _lat; } set { _lat = value; } }

    public double Lng { get { return _lng; } set { _lng = value; } }

    public string Postcode { get { return _postcode; } set { _postcode = value; } }

    public string Rep_code
    {
        get { return _rep_code; }
        set { Rep_code = value; }
    }
    public string Telephone { get { return _telephone; } set { _telephone = value; } 

 }
}
```

I have a CustomCollections class

```
public class CustomerCollection
{

    public List<customerObject> Customers { get; set; }


}
```

My method that loops through dt rows and converts to a customer object

```
  public List<Valueobjects.CustomerCollection> dolist(DataTable temptablename)
    {
        //Create Collection Object
        Valueobjects.CustomerCollection Collection = new Valueobjects.CustomerCollection();

        foreach (DataRow row in temptablename.Rows)
        {
            //Create Customer Object
            Valueobjects.customerObject Customer = new Valueobjects.customerObject();

            //set values of customer object
            Customer.Rep_code = "";
            Customer.Int_rep_key = "";
            Customer.Int_rep_hou = "";
            Customer.Fullname = row["Fullname"].ToString().Trim();
            Customer.Custcode = row["Custcode"].ToString().Trim();
            Customer.Category = row["Category"].ToString().Trim();
            Customer.Address1 = row["Address1"].ToString().Trim();
            Customer.Address2 = row["Address2"].ToString().Trim();
            Customer.Address3 = row["Address3"].ToString().Trim();
            Customer.Postcode = row["Postcode"].ToString().Trim();
            Customer.Country = row["Country"].ToString().Trim();
            Customer.Telephone = row["Telephone"].ToString().Trim();
            Customer.Lat = Convert.ToDouble(row["Lat"]);
            Customer.Lng = Convert.ToDouble(row["Lng"]);
            Customer.County = row["County"].ToString().Trim();

            //add to the collection (list)
            Collection.Customers.Add(Customer);
        }

        temptablename = null;

        return Collection;
    }
```

However when I create a new Customer object and a new CustomerCollection object I am getting an error when adding the customer to the collection list.

Error:

> Error 32  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Classes.Valueobjects.CustomerCollection' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: Your method should only return a `CustomerCollection` instead of a `List<CustomerCollection>`

Comment: `Valueobjects.CustomerCollection` isn't a `List<Valueobjects.CustomerCollection>` that's what the compiler tells you. Btw Use auto properties to make your code look better and concise.

Comment: It seems unnecessary to have a custom class which only contains one property and that is a list. Why not just pass the list around?

Comment: Like create a new list in the method and just return this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is returning a `List<CustomerCollection>`:

```
public List<Valueobjects.CustomerCollection> dolist(DataTable temptablename)
{
    //...
}
```

But the code is trying to return a `CustomerCollection`:

```
return Collection;
```

Just as the error says, these two types are different.

If a `CustomerCollection` is already a collection of customers, then semantically what is a `List<Valueobjects.CustomerCollection>`?  A collection of collections?  It seems like you're over-pluralizing your objects :)

There are two approaches here.  Either return a `CustomerCollection` from the method:

```
public CustomerCollection dolist(DataTable temptablename)
{
    //...
}
```

Or use a `List<Customer>` if you want to use generic lists as your collection containers:

```
public List<Customer> dolist(DataTable temptablename)
{
    //...
    var Collection = new List<Customer>();
    //...
    Collection.Add(Customer);
    //...

    return Collection;
}
```

Side note: You may want to stick to C# conventions for variable naming.  As you can see from the code highlighting here on Stack Overflow, your variable names can easily be mistaken for classes/types, which can cause confusion when supporting the code.

Comment: How can I put the custom list in a viewstate?

Comment: @user4316519: Aside from the question of "why would you want to?" what is stopping you from doing that?  Do you mean an ASP.NET WebForms view state value?  As long as the object can be serialized that should work just fine.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The user will be selecting customers. This will then be added to a list which will populate google maps datasource so it needs to persist on postback. Is it easy to serialize the objects so it can be used in viewstate?

Comment: @user4316519: That sounds like a good use of AJAX requests or regular form elements, not necessarily view state.  Especially if the JavaScript code needs to interact with the data.  View state is just a base-64 encoded serialization of the data.  If JavaScript is going to interact with the data, skipping the base-64 part will make it a lot easier.  (Unless view state has changed a lot since I last saw it years ago.)  Currently the object doesn't look very complicated.  If it's not serializing then that sounds like a good reason for a Stack Overflow question :)

Answer (score 1):

Return a `CustomerCollection` instead of a `List<Valueobjects.CustomerCollection>`:

```
public Valueobjects.CustomerCollection Dolist(DataTable temptablename)
{
// ...
```

Your object *has* a list, it *is* not a list.

MSDN: [Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149(v=vs.110).aspx)